# Deobfusacted crash report on Google Play Developer is not helpful

Tags: android, crash-reports, google-play-console

We use Progaurd on our app. I uploaded the mapping file to Google Play Developer that was output with the corresponding release build at the same time I released the build.  I am still getting crash reports that are not that helpful.  For example a Null Pointer exception in my app that is reported as:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:   at com.########.#####.MainActivity.Disconnect(MainActivity.java)
>
> 1. at  com.########.#####.MainActivity.access$2200 (MainActivity.java)
>      or                     .access$6002 (MainActivity.java)
> 2. at com.########.#####.MainActivity$38.run (MainActivity.java)
> 3. at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
> 4. at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
> 5. at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
> 6. at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
> 7. at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
> 8. at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
> 9. at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)

It does point to the MainActivity.Disconnect, but .access$2200 and MainActivity$38.run are not helpful. Should I expect real names here instead of what it is showing?

I have a separate crash report that is at "MainActivity$5$1.run".  How am I supposed to track that down? Is the mapping file doing it's job and this is how it is, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it a new crash cluster or an old one? If it is an old one verify that you are on the latest report of the crash using the arrows on the left hand side. Old reports won't be de-obfuscated after uploading your mapping file.

Comment: This is the new ANR & Crashes page. This report is definitely from the same version that has the mapping file uploaded.  I made sure it was chosen from the version drop-down at the right.